# Property of a commutative ring that is determined by the prime ideals of the ring

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, big-list

Robert Gilmer, in his paper "[Commutative rings in which each prime ideal is principal](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01350233)", says:

> **Some** well known theorems indicate that certain ideal-theoretic structure properties of a commutative ring $R$ are determined by the *set of prime ideals* of $R$. For example,
> $R$ is Noetherian if and only if each prime ideal of $R$ is finitely generated ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130223/if-r-is-a-commutative-ring-in-which-all-the-prime-ideals-are-finitely-generated/1130240#1130240), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146884/an-ideal-that-is-maximal-among-non-finitely-generated-ideals-is-prime)),
> $R$ is a multiplication ring if and only if each prime ideal of $R$ is a multiplication ideal, and
> if $R$ contains an identity, each nonzero ideal of $R$ is invertible if and only if each nonzero prime ideal of $R$ is invertible.

I would like to have a list of  theorems that a property of a commutative ring $R$ (or $R$-modules) is determined by the prime ideals of $R$.

---

I will gradually list the few things I remember here, and I would appreciate if you complete it:

- Baer's criterion for [injective modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_module) has been refined in many ways including a result that for a commutative Noetherian ring, it suffices to consider only prime ideals instead of all ideals.
- when $R$ is a commutative Noetherian local ring with maximal ideal $m$, global dimension of the ring $R$ can be alternatively defined as the projective dimension of the residue field $R/m$.

Comment: "determined by the set of prime ideals" is a bit ambiguous. What structure do you retain on this set? For instance, you can consider this set as an ordered set. E.g., what "be a multiplication ideal" retains? Without further information I think that any ring property can be disguised into a property in terms of prime ideals.

Comment: properties like the ones listed in the  question.

Comment: Each prime ideal being finitely generated is not a property of the set of prime ideals.

Comment: thank you Fernando Muro . edited. If the question seems dumb, please see the text I quoted from **Gilmer**. I mean examples like ones in that text; Also, what I have written in the *bounty* text.

Comment: Noetherianness is certainly not determined by the (partially ordered) set of prime ideals. Every valuation ring of rank 1 has the same poset of prime ideals, but there are non-Noetherian valuation rings of rank 1.

Comment: R is Noetherian if and only if each prime ideal of R is finitely generated

Answer (score 1):

[Proposition 1.2.10(a)](https://books.google.com/books?id=LF6CbQk9uScC&pg=PA11) in "[Cohen–Macaulay Rings](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511608681)" by W. Bruns, H.J. Herzog: if $R$ is a Noetherian ring, $I$ an ideal of $R$, and $M$ a finite $R$-module, then
$$\operatorname{grade} (I,M)= \inf \{\operatorname{depth} M_p \mid p \in V(I)\}.$$